# Clustered and Grouped Bar Chart in Mathematica v8.0

Tags: plotting, graphics

How would I create a clustered and grouped bar chart that looks like this (which was painstakingly created using Excel)?
[image]

I have seen examples for Mathematica v6.0 but none for Mathematica v8.0.

The data I used to create this chart is as follows:

```
"Cluster","KPI","Bar","Value"
"Cluster1","Utilisation","Bar1",92
"Cluster2","Utilisation","Bar1",78
"Cluster3","Utilisation","Bar1",68
"Cluster4","Utilisation","Bar1",56
"Cluster5","Utilisation","Bar1",84
"Cluster1","Availability","Bar1",8
"Cluster2","Availability","Bar1",21
"Cluster3","Availability","Bar1",24
"Cluster4","Availability","Bar1",36
"Cluster5","Availability","Bar1",7
"Cluster1","Utilisation","Bar2",92
"Cluster2","Utilisation","Bar2",78
"Cluster3","Utilisation","Bar2",72
"Cluster4","Utilisation","Bar2",59
"Cluster5","Utilisation","Bar2",67
"Cluster1","Availability","Bar2",8
"Cluster2","Availability","Bar2",16
"Cluster3","Availability","Bar2",23
"Cluster4","Availability","Bar2",31
"Cluster5","Availability","Bar2",23
"Cluster1","Utilisation","Bar3",77
"Cluster2","Utilisation","Bar3",82
"Cluster3","Utilisation","Bar3",78
"Cluster4","Utilisation","Bar3",66
"Cluster5","Utilisation","Bar3",85
"Cluster1","Availability","Bar3",23
"Cluster2","Availability","Bar3",14
"Cluster3","Availability","Bar3",20
"Cluster4","Availability","Bar3",28
"Cluster5","Availability","Bar3",9
"Cluster1","Utilisation","Bar4",100
"Cluster2","Utilisation","Bar4",83
"Cluster3","Utilisation","Bar4",75
"Cluster4","Utilisation","Bar4",59
"Cluster5","Utilisation","Bar4",80
"Cluster1","Availability","Bar4",0
"Cluster2","Availability","Bar4",16
"Cluster3","Availability","Bar4",20
"Cluster4","Availability","Bar4",35
"Cluster5","Availability","Bar4",14
```

---

For convenience, here is the same sample data in a different form:

```
{{"Cluster1", {{92, 8}, {92, 8}, {77, 23}, {100, 0}}},
 {"Cluster2", {{78, 21}, {78, 16}, {82, 14}, {83, 16}}},
 {"Cluster3", {{68, 24}, {72, 23}, {78, 20}, {75, 20}}},
 {"Cluster4", {{56, 36}, {59, 31}, {66, 28}, {59, 35}}},
 {"Cluster5", {{84, 7}, {67, 23}, {85, 9}, {80, 14}}}}
```

Or:

```
{{"Cluster1",{{"Bar1",{92,8}},{"Bar2",{92,8}},{"Bar3",{77,23}},{"Bar4",{100,0}}}},
{"Cluster2",{{"Bar1",{78,21}},{"Bar2",{78,16}},{"Bar3",{82,14}},{"Bar4",{83,16}}}},
{"Cluster3",{{"Bar1",{68,24}},{"Bar2",{72,23}},{"Bar3",{78,20}},{"Bar4",{75,20}}}},
{"Cluster4",{{"Bar1",{56,36}},{"Bar2",{59,31}},{"Bar3",{66,28}},{"Bar4",{59,35}}}},
{"Cluster5",{{"Bar1",{84,7}},{"Bar2",{67,23}},{"Bar3",{85,9}},{"Bar4",{80,14}}}}}
```

Comment: Can you generate some fake sample data? If it were just a single cluster you could use the `ChartLayout -> "Percentile"` option in `BarChart`, but for multiple clusters, you might have to roll your own.

Comment: I wasn't of the best way to lay out the data (which is why I originally didn't). However I have placed the data in flat format above in the question.

Comment: Well, only a minimal example was needed... so 2 bars and 2 clusters should be sufficient.

Comment: before spending some time on this can you clarify where you have said you have seen examples for Mma 6.0 but not 8.0. Does this mean you tried a V6.0 example in V8.0 and had problems?

Comment: Looking at the v6.0 example further it appears they add a 0 data point to create the clusters; the example is given on [link](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Nov/msg00846.html) and the code is `Needs["BarCharts\`"]
gr = StackedBarChart[{2, 2, 0, 4, 5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5}, 
  BarStyle -> {Yellow, Black}, 
  Ticks -> {{{1.5, "1, 2"}, {4.5, "3, 4"}}, Automatic}]`.

Comment: when you evaluate `Needs["BarCharts`"]` you will get a message with a link to a page that shows how to transform the code to V8. The link showed me that your example would be written as `BarChart[{{2, 2, 0, 4, 5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5}} // Transpose, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartStyle -> {Yellow, Black}, 
 Ticks -> {{{1.5, "1, 2"}, {4.5, "3, 4"}}, Automatic}]`. Hopefully that might help. (You may need to check out the `ChartLabels` examples in the `BarChart` documentation.). If no answer is posted I'll have a go at it this afternoon (3-4 hours from now)

Comment: Sorry for not looking at the v6.0 example more carefully in the first place.  Yes - I will read the documentation on chart labelling (and data manipulation).  Thanks.

Comment: thats ok. I'd forgotten that so many changes had taken place from V6 to V8!

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks for offering to help. I ended up using frame ticks to add a "secondary x axis" (code in question).  I am still working on the best way to manipulate the data (and automate this).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately I was not able to come back to this problem during the day. This is a bit of a hack created after some red wine induced insomnia but here goes:

First a labelling function:

```
ClearAll[labeler];

labeler[v_, {i_, j_}, __] := (Which[
   j == 1, Clear[tmp]; tmp = v,
   j == 2, tmp = tmp + v
   ]; Placed[Row[{tmp}], Center])
```

Then the code for the bar chart (note that I had to add {0,0} as a spacer. This seems an unreasonable approach to take but was quick to achieve the desired result):

```
BarChart[{{92, 8}, {92, 8}, {77, 23}, {100, 0}, {0, 0}, {78, 21}, {78,
    16}, {82, 14}, {83, 16}, {0, 0}, {68, 24}, {72, 23}, {78, 
   20}, {75, 20}, {0, 0}, {56, 36}, {59, 31}, {66, 28}, {59, 35}, {0, 
   0}, {84, 7}, {67, 23}, {85, 9}, {80, 14}},
 AspectRatio -> 0.4,
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 10, GrayLevel[0.6]],
 BarSpacing -> 0.2,
 ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[]],
 ChartLabels -> {Flatten[
    Table[{"Bar\[VeryThinSpace]1", "Bar\[VeryThinSpace]2", "Bar3", 
      "Bar\[VeryThinSpace]4", ""}, {5}]], None},
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartStyle -> {RGBColor[0.6, 0.8, 0.196], RGBColor[1., 0.743, 0]},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}},
 FrameLabel -> {None, 
   Style["Utilization/Availability (% of Calendar Time)", 
    GrayLevel[0.2]], None, None},
 FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7],
 FrameTicks -> {{{2.5, "\nCluster1", 0}, {7.5, "\nCluster2", 
     0}, {12.5, "\nCluster3", 0}, {17.5, "\nCluster4", 0}, {22.5, 
     "\nCluster4", 0}}, Automatic, None, None},
 FrameTicksStyle -> GrayLevel[0.2],
 GridLines -> {None, Automatic},
 GridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7],
 ImageSize -> 800,
 LabelingFunction -> labeler,
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0.3, 0.3}, {0, 0}},
 Ticks -> {None, Automatic}]
```

Below is a screen shot:

[image]

and your plot:

[image]

I haven't added the legend but you'll find plenty of examples of good legend code here (@Jens being the best and most often cited) -- main thing is avoid the bundled `PlotLegends`. Also if you want something identical to the Excel plot you would need to remove minor ticks on the y axis and have major ticks and grid lines every 10 units.

To get the lower labels with the horizontal bar (mimic the Excel plot) I would use `Labeled` with the `Grid` of the labels and a top `Divider` line.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  For the chart and the references/suggestions for moving forward.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from provided comments, the following code will format the labels (centering the "*cluster*" label), however it is only an interim solution (more work is required to determine how to format and manipulate the data)

```
BarChart[{{92, 8}, {92, 8}, {0, 0}, {78, 8}, {72, 7}}, 
ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
Ticks -> None, 
PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {8, 0}}, 
Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[White, FontColor -> Black], 
FrameTicks -> {{{1.5, "Cluster1", 0}, {4.5, "Cluster2", 0}}, None, None, None}, 
ChartLabels -> {{"bar1", "bar2", "", "bar1", "bar2"}, None}, 
ChartLegends -> {"Av", "Ut"}] /. 
Column[List[a : Grid[List[___]] ..]] :> Column[Reverse@List@a]
```

Answer (score 3):

I was asked how to do this recently and came up with an independent approach using `Show` and `RectangleChart`. It was tested in version 9 but should work in version 8. It automatically formats the data as required, and cycles the colours in the stack if needed, as long as the list of colours is longer than the number of bars in each stack.

```
groupstackBarChart[rawdata : {__?MatrixQ}, 
   options : OptionsPattern[{groupstackBarChart, RectangleChart, Graphics}]] /; 
  Length@rawdata > 1 :=   
 Module[{n = Length[rawdata], 
   bs = With[{ovbs = OptionValue[BarSpacing]}, 
     Which[ovbs === Automatic, 0.2, VectorQ[ovbs], First@ovbs, 
      NumericQ[ovbs], ovbs, True, 0.2]], cs, step1, transformeddata, zeros}, 
   cs = With[{csraw = OptionValue[ChartStyle]}, 
    Which[VectorQ[csraw], 
     Partition[PadRight[csraw, Total[Dimensions[#][[2]] & /@ rawdata], csraw], 
      n], MatrixQ[csraw] && Length[csraw] >= Length[rawdata], csraw, 
     True, NestList[Lighter /@ # &, 
      Darker /@ {Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Purple, Pink, Gray}, 
      n - 1]]];
  step1 = (Riffle[#, zeros] & /@ Map[{1, #} &, rawdata, {-1}]) /. 
    zeros -> Sequence @@ ConstantArray[{{1, 0}}, n - 1]; 
 (*  If you put the list directly in the Riffle, 
  it alternates between the elements, which is not what you want*)  
  transformeddata = 
   MapIndexed[RotateRight[#1, First[#2] - 1] &, 
    Join[#, ConstantArray[{{1 - bs, 0}}, n - 1]] & /@ step1]; 
  Show[Sequence @@ (MapThread[
      RectangleChart[#1, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarSpacing -> bs, ChartStyle -> #2, 
        Sequence @@  FilterRules[{options}, Options[RectangleChart]]] &, 
        {transformeddata, cs}]),  Sequence @@ FilterRules[{options}, Options[Graphics]]
   ]]
```

Here are some examples

```
testdata = RandomVariate[TriangularDistribution[{-0.5, 2}], {3, 5, 3}];
testdata2 = RandomVariate[TriangularDistribution[{-0.5, 2}], {4, 4, 4}];
```

A simple example

```
groupstackBarChart[testdata]
```

[image]

Showing the colour cycling, though this can be confusing if you have negative values:

```
groupstackBarChart[testdata, ChartStyle -> {Orange, Gray, Cyan, Purple}]
```

[image]

Something closer to what was requested:

```
groupstackBarChart[testdata2, 
 ChartStyle -> 
  ConstantArray[{RGBColor[0.6, 0.8, 0.196], RGBColor[1., 0.743, 0]}, 
   6], FrameTicks -> {Join[
    Table[{i, "Cluster " <> ToString[Round[(i + 4)/7]], {0, 0}}, {i, 
      3, 25.5, 7.25}]], Range[0, 3, 0.5]}, Axes -> None, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[6.5, 28, 
    7.25], {{0, Directive[Black, Dashing[{}]]}, 
    Sequence @@ Range[0.5, 3, 0.5]}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashing[Small]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using `FrameTicks` and directly specifying values by using `ChartLabels`:

```
errors = {
    { "Molecule", "Delta H", "Relative Time" },
    {"HF/6-31G(d)", 64.6011, 1. },
    {"B3LYP/6-31G(d)", 69.384, 1.4413 },
    {"MP2/6-31G(d)", 19.2196, 1.38462 },
    {"MP4/6-31G(d)", 24.462, 7.76113 }
}

BarChart[ 
    errors[[ 2 ;;, 2 ;; ]], 
    ChartLegends -> errors[[ 1, 2 ;; ]], 
    ChartLabels -> { Placed[ prettyData[[ 2 ;; 5, 1 ]], Axis ], Placed[ { "", "", "", "" }, Axis ] }
]
```

[image]

It should be noted that in this case two were required inside the table for `ChartLabels`